# Can't install store apps in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have SharePoint 2016 on-premises and am attempting to set it up to be able to install apps on it.  I have followed the directions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236(v=office.16).aspx leaving out the certificates as I am not using SSL at this time.  All of the setup steps work correctly and I am able to see and select apps from the SharePoint store.  However, when I attempt to install an app, I get the extremely helpful message "Sorry, something went wrong with adding the app.  Click to retry."  The only information that appears to be relevant in the logs is the following:

```
CITPSession::PeekProj() not defined; clearing METADATA_WEB_* flags 0x00000000
Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002
<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
<nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=/VirtoImageSlider/Lists/Settings ,METADATAFLAGS=59
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack>
</nativestack>, StackTrace:    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListInstanceElement.GetExistingList(SPWeb web, Boolean fShouldDeleteExistingListIfNecessary)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListInstanceElement.EnsureListExists(SPWeb web, Boolean bCreateFromSTP, Boolean bUserFeature)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListInstanceElement.ElementActivated(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSqlCommand sqlcmdAppendOnly, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionListInstances(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(Guid featureId, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.EnsureWebFeaturesActivated(SPUserSolution solution)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.ActivateSolution(SPWeb web, SPUserSolution solution)     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTaskCore()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTask()     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()


Exception while executing task 3792ac05-590d-41fb-a57c-9c92c3d79ab3 of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup in job 8967cc31-b0dc-4cd4-94ec-c4f74db87b0f for instance 89a55f36-f726-48ae-bece-02a80d829f33 sitesubscription 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, rollback = False: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception e, Boolean force)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(Guid featureId, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.EnsureWebFeaturesActivated(SPUserSolution solution)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.ActivateSolution(SPWeb web, SPUserSolution solution)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTaskCore()

Returning error with exception information. Type: App, Source: AppWeb, Detail: There was a problem with activating the app web definition., Correlation: 8967cc31-b0dc-4cd4-94ec-c4f74db87b0f, Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception e, Boolean force)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(Guid featureId, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.EnsureWebFeaturesActivated(SPUserSolution solution)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.ActivateSolution(SPWeb web, SPUserSolution solution)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTaskCore()

Updating app instance 89a55f36-f726-48ae-bece-02a80d829f33 in site ed72e51f-4115-4d54-9816-c6a12f5de80f to have error <SPAppInstanceErrorDetails xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><CorrelationId>8967cc31-b0dc-4cd4-94ec-c4f74db87b0f</CorrelationId><ErrorDetailToken>AppLifecycleError_UserCode_Activation</ErrorDetailToken><ErrorType>App</ErrorType><Source>AppWeb</Source><exceptionDetailedMessage>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964 ---&gt; System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl, String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback pModuleContext)&#xD;    -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception e, Boolean force)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(Guid featureId, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUserSolutionCollection.EnsureWebFeaturesActivated(SPUserSolution solution)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.ActivateSolution(SPWeb web, SPUserSolution solution)&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Packaging.SPUserCodeSolutionDeploymentGroup.Deploy()&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppTask.DeployOperation()&#xD;   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Lifecycle.MonitoredTaskExecution.DoTaskCore()</exceptionDetailedMessage><exceptionMessage>Exception from HRESULT: 0x81070964</exceptionMessage></SPAppInstanceErrorDetails>
```

This happens with any app that I attempt to install.  Googling the error numbers comes up with a couple of sites that talk about having extra files in an app that you are developing, but I doubt this is the case since I'm using apps from the store.  Beyond that, I can't come up with anything.  Does anyone have any advice on how to get these apps to install?

Comment: Understand that not using SSL is a major security risk, akin to sending usernames/passwords in plain text. You can intercept and replay the user's token, effectively granting the same level of access in SharePoint as the user. Do you have any additional information from the ULS log?

Comment: Yes.  This is a dev site only and it's isolated.  I first tried setting up apps with SSL and they weren't working (different errors, though) and then I decided to start fresh and remove SSL so that I could remove as many factors as possible.  What other information from the log would you be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check things below:

1. Check if you have configured farm for apps correctly according to the article below.

[Prepare your SharePoint 2013 farm for App development and debugging.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging/)

2. Run SharePoint 2016 products configuration wizard.
3. Do not use system account when installing the apps in SharePoint.

Comment: All of that was covered in the article I referenced.  I've attempted installs with three different accounts to ensure it wasn't an account issue.